# PHP 5.3 only Systems/Frameworks

Tags: php, frameworks, system

What PHP systems or frameworks have gone 5.3 only, or contain a significant number of features that require/take-advantage of PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Alloy Framework](http://alloyframework.org) - It's a new PHP 5.3+ Hierarchal MVC Framework that works a little differently than most other MVC frameworks.

The main differences to other framework projects are primarily:

1. Modular Organization - single folder for a group of controllers/views/entities that are created for the same structure - "blog" or "events", etc.
2. HMVC (Hierarchal MVC) - Allows module sub-dispatches anywhere within views or controllers - extremely useful for "wiget" type structures within layouts or nested views. Helps promote code re-use for common structures like "comments", "tags", "ratings", etc.
3. More explicitness - view objects are explicitly retuned by the controller method for display instead of implicitly loaded, etc.

Read more on the [Architecture](http://alloyframework.org/manual/architecture/) page of the manual.

The [URL Router](http://alloyframework.org/manual/url-router/) is also very nice and borrows a lot of concepts from Merb and Rails.

Comment: +1 for alloy, i've been tinkering with this and several other 5.3 frameworks over the last couple of weeks. Alloy (and Lithium) are hands down the most interesting/innovative frameworks out there at the moment - lightweight and useful

Answer (score 4):

Frameworks:

- [ZendFramework2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2)
- [Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony)

ORMs:

- [Doctrine2](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2)

Answer (score 3):

[Symfony 2.0](http://symfony-reloaded.org/)

Answer (score 2):

There's also the Lithium framework, which is quite similar in design to CakePHP

http://li3.me/

**Update:** I would also highly recommend that you check out [Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/)